# How to continue processing a VBA macro in case of an error?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I have a problem.

I have an excel file with a macro in VBA that allows me to calculate the distance between two cities in kms :

[image]

The problem is that if the destination city does not exist the script stops and puts this error that says that the index does not belong to the selection.

[image]

When I select "Debug" it highlights this line in yellow:

```
 .Range("C" & i).Value = Split(Split(Txt, "id=""distanciaRuta"">")(1), "</strong>")(0)
```

How to do that even if the city is not found to continue the execution of the script by leaving a blank in the box?

```
Option Explicit

Public Const DIST = "http://www.distance2villes.com/recherche?source="


Sub Distance()
Dim lg As Integer, i As Integer
Dim Url As String, Txt As String

    With Sheets("Feuil1")
        lg = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lg
            Url = DIST & .Range("A" & i).Value & "&destination=" & .Range("B" & i).Value
            With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
                .Open "GET", Url, False
                .send
                Txt = .responseText
            End With
            .Range("C" & i).Value = Split(Split(Txt, "id=""distanciaRuta"">")(1), "</strong>")(0)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: For the time being, you can add a line before and a line after: `On Error Resume Next` : `.Range....` : `On Error Goto 0`. Note that this is not a proper solution, neither is your extraction of the data. Hopefully, someone more qualified will explain the issues.

Comment: Thank you I will try

Comment: It is necessary like that? it makes me a mistake   
`On Error Resume Next

            .Range("C" & i).Value = Split(Split(Txt, "id=""distanciaRuta"">")(1), "</strong>")(0)
            .Range.... : On Error Goto 0`

Comment: A line before and a line after means 1. line `On Error Resume Next`, 2.line `.Range....`, and 3. line `On Error Goto 0`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't quite understand! Thank you for your answer, it leaves a gap and goes on to the next one. What did you mean when you said that my solution is not appropriate?

Comment: Have the code make a list of the cities with errors - then investigate why? Like typing errors? Or operators who can’t spell?

Comment: Yes, I wanted the code to leave some blanks so that I could see the problematic cities. From what I found as an error is that I am given the site and some cities are abbreviated or missing dashes for example. Is it possible to extract the problematic ones to process them faster? @SolarMike

Comment: Here is a part of the cities where I have no distance for example:
 `SWANSEA, ROMA TRIGORIA,PARIS 14, LANGENFELD RHEINLAND,HM HIPPOLYT, PEMBROKE, DL DEN HAAG ,PARIS 14, WESTERLANDSYLT`

Comment: Do some research to solve these: e.g. `ABERTAWE, ROMA, LANGENFELD, PEMBROKE DL, DEN HAAG, WESTERLAND SYLT, WESTERLAND, SYLT` where e.g. `Abertawe` is the Welsh name for `Swansea`, `Westerland` and `Sylt` are probably the same, etc.

Comment: Yes I think the name errors just come from mistakes like that. The problem is that the list I am given contains more than 5000 cities and I have to go over each one that has a problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to avoid throwing exceptions when you can. In your case, a null check is what you want

```
Option Explicit

Public Const DIST = "http://www.distance2villes.com/recherche?source="


Sub Distance()
Dim lg As Integer, i As Integer
Dim Url As String, Txt As String

    With Sheets("Feuil1")
        lg = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lg
            Url = DIST & .Range("A" & i).Value & "&destination=" & .Range("B" & i).Value
            With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
                .Open "GET", Url, False
                .send
                Txt = .responseText
            End With
            
            ' Only set the value if we got a response
            If Txt <> vbNullString Then .Range("C" & i).Value = Split(Split(Txt, "id=""distanciaRuta"">")(1), "</strong>")(0)

            ' Clear our variable before next
            Txt = vbNullString
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

To continue past an error you can use `On Error Resume Next` but I would only use this as a last resort on a single line where you know there may be an error you can't avoid.

If there are occasional errors it's best to use an error handler. You can write a simple one with an `On Error Goto errorHandler` pattern or if you are feeling adventurous you can look to well developed solutions for inspiration: https://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog.asp

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: But I have to add the line `On Error Resume Next` before your modifications if I want the program not to stop when it does not find a city?

Comment: No. I'm saying "never do that". If you think you need to resume next, think again. Ignoring bugs doesn't make them go away.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right.  Thank you for your answers